# Zero downtime deployment with Airflow

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

My team is using Airflow to schedule ETL jobs. Right now we're on LocalExecutor. We also do continuous integration.

Right now, when we ship certain types of changes (e.g. adding a new operator) we have to restart the prod airflow scheduler in order for the change to be picked up. When we restart the scheduler, any actively running tasks get killed and have to be restarted, which is a huge pain.

I'm trying to figure out how to either avoid the need to restart the scheduler or to prevent running tasks from being interrupted by a scheduler restart. I've read some articles about the topic such as [this one](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/upgrading-airflow-with-zero-downtime-8df303760c96), but none that use LocalExecutor.

Will upgrading to Celery as an executor be necessary to accomplish this or is there a way to do it on LocalExecutor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to achieve what you want if you use LocalExecutor. With CeleryExecutor at least the currently running tasks will continue running even if you restart the scheduler. However you need to deploy the new stuff to the workers (Celery) too, but that can be implemented properly by sending graceful shutdown signals to existing workers, and creating a new set of workers with updated code.